# ¿Còmo agregar el Result Type a un SP agregado a LINQ (programando en C#)?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, pivot

Necesito que linq establesca la propiedad Return Type al agregar un SP desde SQL 2014 para poder asignar ese Resultset como DataSource a un DataGridView (devexpress)
Còmo puedo hacer para que linq me genere esa parte del codigo o como puedo hacer (manualmente?) si no lo hace linq

Dejo tanto el codigo de SQL(este còdigo me genera columnas dinàmicas dependiendo cuantas fechas existen) como la foto de la propiedad en blanco:

```
`ALTER PROCEDURE [wan].[sp_PivotViewPedidoDetalleLastSent]
@SedeID int
as
begin

DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnFechaPedidoID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition as nvarchar(500);

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnFechaPedidoID = ISNULL(@ColumnFechaPedidoID + ',','') + 
QUOTENAME(FechaPedidoID)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT FechaPedidoID FROM [wan].[VistaPedidoDetallePivot]) AS 
Fecha

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 

SET @DynamicPivotQuery =
N'select * from 
(
SELECT p.SedeID, ISNULL(pd.[Send],0) [send], pd.ProductoID, 
vpdp.FechaPedidoID FROM wan.PedidoDetalle pd
INNER JOIN wan.Pedido p on p.ID = pd.PedidoID
join wan.vistapedidodetallepivot vpdp on pd.ID = vpdp.ID
WHERE p.SedeID = @SedeID
group by /*pd.ID,P.ID,*/p.SedeID,pd.ProductoID,pd.[Send],FechaPedidoID
) pv
  pivot
  (
  sum(pv.[Send])
  for pv.[FechaPedidoID] in ('+@ColumnFechaPedidoID+')
  ) pvt;'

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@SedeID int';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery, @ParmDefinition,
@SedeID = @SedeID;
end`
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si necesitan algo màs me dicen
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hey porque tengo -1 en mi puntuacion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq no esta pensado para retornar entidades que generen tipos dinamicos, este es bueno cuando trabajas entidades tipadas.

En el foro de stackowerflow en ingles se planteo lo mismo

[Dynamic SQL based stored procedure call in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667815/dynamic-sql-based-stored-procedure-call-in-entity-framework)

Tambien aqui

[Dynamic stored procedures not working in Entity Framework](https://forums.asp.net/t/1930300.aspx?Dynamic%20stored%20procedures%20not%20working%20in%20Entity%20Framework)

creo que la mejor respuesta seria:

> EF is best suited to expose database data as strongly typed .NET objects but here it will be totally dynamic, my personal preference would be likely to NOT use EF here

que basicamente responde lo mismo que plantee al principio

Hacerlo manualmente implica tener que usar ado.net realizando el Fill() de un datatable.

El Fill() seria hacer uso de `SqlDataAdapter`, algo como ser

```
DataTabla dt = new DataTable(); 
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring")) 
{ 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("<storedprocedure>", conn); 
    cmd.CommandType = SqlCommandType.StoredProcedure; 

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", valor); 

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 
    da.Fill(dt); 
}
```

Comment: Gracias, Me podrias por favor ejemplificar què es lo del fill() del datatable?  
edited:
ya lo tengo claro sos un crack!!!

Comment: Sabes como ejecutar el procedimiento que me pide parametros desde el sqldataadapter?

Comment: @IngSysTJ edit la pregunta agregando un ejemplo de ado.net donde se realzia el Fill() de un datatable

Comment: edit = editè ---> eso signifca??
O me estàs mandando a que yo edite mi pregunta?
@Leandro, me equivoquè de artìculo, èsta es la forma correcta:
"Sabès como ejecutar UN procedimiento que me pide parametros (serverside) desde UN sqldataadapter (clientside)?"
Y es que para cuando formulè esa pregunta no habìas agregado el còdigo que encontrè por otro lado. se te agradece prix .l Y es que sòlo llevo 3 meses aprendiendo a como programar y no habìa tocado esa parte pues estoy entregando sistemas a empresas y segùn me dijeron, te ahorra màs tiempo programar con el ''EF''  que con ''ADO''....

Comment: boten mi pregunta porque el sistema no me deja eliminarla y a d+ està en -2 osea no sirve de nada que yo me de cuenta que tiene cuenta negativa.